# WSO2 Tenant specific Passive STS does not send claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 5.1 identity server that is configured as a multi tenant host. I have a tenant configured with a Passive STS. The response documents from that Passive STS do not include any of the claims defined in the Claim Configuration for the Passive STS in the tenant. I only get the subject assertion. If I configure the same Passive STS on the global tenant, or on a server that is not multi tenant, I get the expected response document with the subject assertion and all the mapped claims. Interestingly, the tenant document is also signed with  the global certificate and not the tenant specific certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to update the passive sts url from the client\web app.

Suppose you have tenant called 'foo.com'. Then set the Identity Server's passive sts url as,
`https://localhost:9443/passivests?tenantDomain=foo.com`

Above will point 'foo.com' tenant's passive sts endpoint while following url points super tenant\global tenant's passive sts endpiont.
`https://localhost:9443/passivests`

HTH,
DarRay